Maximum Number of Resource in an API
I wanted to know maximum number of resources attached to a single api that can can developed and deployed in wso2 apim
Just wanted to know maximum range of resources in an  apis that can published and range depends on what factor of wso2
Count of the max. resources in single API

Technically, there is no such limitation on the resource count in the WSO2 API Manager. However, it is better to follow best practices when developing an API.
